# Exception thrown when trying to set General Link value

Tags: content-editor

I am working on a template that has a General Link field. When I am trying to set the Insert link with the Sitecore Content Editor I am getting the following error:

[image]

I am working on Sitecore 8.0 (rev.150121)

The other General link options are working fine:

- Insert media link
- Insert external link
- Insert anchor
- Insert email
- Insert JavaScript

I added a new field to the same template containing the general link field as well, and it is working fine - even for the Insert link option.

When viewing the raw values for the item, I have found that the link had a default value set to "".  When I removed it and saved it, everything is working fine, the other testing link that I added does not have this default value, and the field on the template itself does not have such a value or any default value.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible for you to copy and paste the exception + stack trace into your question? It will make it more searchable and assist others who have the same problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue you reported was fixed in Sitecore Experience Platform 8.0 rev. 150621 (8.0 Update-4) and you can upgrade your solution to address the problem.

Please take a look at the reference number 416281 in Sitecore CMS release notes on for additional details on the fix: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/8%200/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2080%20Update4/Release%20notes

If upgrade is not an option for you, we suggest you implement the following workaround to resolve the issue on your current solution:

1. Place the attached Sitecore.Support.416281 assembly to the \bin folder of your solution;
2. Open /sitecore/system/Field types/Link Types/General Link item in the Core database;
3. Clean up its Control field;
4. Put Sitecore.Support.416281 in the Assembly field and Sitecore.Support.Link in the Class field;
5. Save changes.

Please download the assembly : https://www.dropbox.com/s/hl7ho6wmnca8u2y/Sitecore.Support.416281.dll?dl=0

Comment: Thank you the work around solve the issue since the upgrade is not an option for me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Hero Link URL field has a standard value associated with it and that is what is causing the default value. Can you check to see if the standard values for that field is correct? You may need to view the raw values on the standard values item to make sure that the `<link>` tag is not in there. Save the standard values item, create a new item, and see if the new item is still having that error.

Comment: there is no standard values on the item nor the template, the work around that Sitecore Climber provide me with fix the issue